# String index out of range 11 error java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have written this code and it compiles fine but when i try to run it give me an error saying String index out of range: 11. Could anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

import java.util.*;
class Question2
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String[] section1 = {"Curie, Marie", "Feynman, Richard", "Germain, Sophie",
                         "Turing, Alan"};
    String[] section2 = {"Bolt, Usain", "Graf, Steffi","Hamm, Mia",};
    String[] section3 = {"Bach, Johann Sebastian", "Beethoven, Ludwig van", 
                         "Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus", "Schumann, Clara"};
    String [] merged = mergeSortedArrays(section1,section2);

    //String[] merged =  mergeSortedArrays(mergeSortedArrays(section1, section2),section3);
    for (int z =0; z < merged.length-4; z++) {
     System.out.println(merged[z] + ", ");
    }


}

// Do not change the method header
public static String[] mergeSortedArrays(String[] a1, String[] a2) { //method for merging and ordering


    String[] temp  = new String[a1.length + a2.length]; // new array with size of the two input arrays
    int x; // variable declared for a for loop and other purposes
    for(x = 0; x< a1.length -1; x++){ //1st for loop to put in names from a1 to the new array 

      temp[x] = a1[x]; // code to store the strings from one array to the other 

    }

    for(int y = 0; y <a2.length -1; y++) {  //2nd for loop to put in names from a2 to the new array

     temp[x] = a2[y];         // code to store the strings from one array to the other
      x = x +1;              //increments x, to help incease the index of the new array
    }
    String[] tempor = new String[1]; 
    boolean finish = true; // boolean to help break the while loop used later

    while( finish == true) { // while loop to check the names to make them in order
       finish = false;       //makes the boolean false
     for(int i = 0; i < temp.length-1 ; i ++) {  // 3rd for loop. To check between two strings
        String temporary1 = temp[i];          // string variable that stores a string from the new array
        String temporary2 = temp[i+1];        // string variable that stores the next string from the same new array
        int minimum = Math.min(temporary1.length(), temporary2.length());
      for(int j = 0; j < minimum -1; j++) { //4th for loop. To check between characters of the two strings


       if((int)(temporary1.charAt(j)) == (int)(temporary2.charAt(j))) { //ascii value of same index characters of the two strings are compared. An int casting is done here. 
        //do nothing. If the two ascii values are same we iterate the for loop and compare the ascii values of the next two same index characters
        //move to next character
      }


       else{ //if two asciis are not same, we compare to see which one is bigger/smaller.


         if((int)temporary1.charAt(j) > (int)temporary2.charAt(j)) { //condition, if ascii of first char is greater, we swap the two strings
           tempor[0] = temp[i + 1]; 
           temp[i + 1] = temp[i];
           temp[i] = tempor[0];
           finish = true;
           j = j + 100;
         }

         else{
           j = j + 100;
           //do nothing
         }

       }


      }

     }

    }



  return temp;
```

}
}

Comment: The code is accessing the 12th element (index 11) of an array that has a length of less than 12. *Search* for the error message and *read* questions asked by others, so that you can get some suggestions.

Comment: First express what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing 12th element. take a look below

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length ; i ++) {
    String temporary1 =""+ temp[i];
    String temporary2 = ""+temp[i+1]; // when i is at last element you are accessing something after  that element which is invalid.
    // everything else
```

So you have to loop it to temp.length-1. the same is happening in more places. try rectifying it.

Comment: Hey I fixed the problem you pointed out. Now its showing me another error "Null pointer exception". Im pretty new at coding and it would be great if you could help me out with this. I edited my code.

Comment: can you give the whole stack trace of the null pointer exception and whatever output you are getting.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Question2.mergeSortedArrays(Question2.java:48)
 at Question2.main(Question2.java:13)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
>

Comment: in the 1st loop and the 2nd loop the comparison condition should be "<a1.length" and "<a2.length"

Comment: and this loop in the main function
 for (int z =0; z < merged.length; z++) {
     System.out.println(merged[z] + ", ");
    }